# PhpStorm Autocomplete Symfony2 with Source Elsewhere

Tags: symfony, phpstorm

Is there anyway with PhpStorm to configure it so it can look at Symfony2 source code without it being in my active project.

The reason I ask is I've set up my project in the recommended way, and so my repository only has my own code (not the Symfony2 code). Due to this setup, PhpStorm can't autocomplete any of the Symfony stuff because it doesn't know where the code is.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Settings -> PHP -> (include path) -> Select the directory on your filesystem.

It will be included in your "External Libraries" in your project window.